# How to disable button in asp.net mvc by c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, view

I try to disable a button when the user press the disable button ,the disable will be pop-up a dialog to let user confirm ,if user click yes ,then set the disablebtn  button disable ,
How can i implement this ?

```
<td data-title="Function">
@Html.ActionLink("View", "JustView", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

                @if (item.Review == EnableType.NO && item.Change == EnableType.NO )
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

                }

                else if (item.Expired == EnableType.NO && item.Review == EnableType.YES)
                {
                    <input type="button" id ="disablebtn" class="delmenu btn btn-primary" value="Disable" data-id="@item.Id" />
                }
                @Html.Hidden("ID", item.Id)
            </td>

   <script>
    $('.delmenu').click(function() {
        var msg = "Are you sure want to disable?";
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        if (confirm(msg) == true) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "ID01")',
                data: { id: id },
                type: 'post',
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "Success") {
                       //when get success how to set the button disable ??????
                        location.href = "/ID01/Index";
                       
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable the disablebtn button after the user confirms, you can add the following line of code inside the success function of your AJAX request:

```
$('#disablebtn').prop('disabled', true);
```

Here's an updated version of your code with the modification:

```
<td data-title="Function">
    @Html.ActionLink("View", "JustView", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
    @if (item.Review == EnableType.NO && item.Change == EnableType.NO )
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
    }
    else if (item.Expired == EnableType.NO && item.Review == EnableType.YES)
    {
        <input type="button" id="disablebtn" class="delmenu btn btn-primary" value="Disable" data-id="@item.Id" />
    }
    @Html.Hidden("ID", item.Id)
</td>
<script>
    $('.delmenu').click(function() {
        var msg = "Are you sure you want to disable?";
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        if (confirm(msg) == true) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "ID01")',
                data: { id: id },
                type: 'post',
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "Success") {
                        $('#disablebtn').prop('disabled', true);
                        location.href = "/ID01/Index";
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

After the AJAX request is successful and the response is "Success," the line `$('#disablebtn').prop('disabled', true);` will disable the disablebtn button.

Comment: Patrik ,
thanks for your help, but I have try to add $('#disablebtn').prop('disabled', true); as you said ,but still cann't  disable the button

Comment: This code should work. You checked in the console if you have an error or if you have access to the button "$('#disablebtn')", Maybe your problem is in the ajax part or is the part successful or not?